# Does Euler number $e$ have a role in kinematics?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, mathematics, displacement

Euler number $e$ is often explained with the example of compound continuous interest.

I was wondering if it could also be illustrated with an example about the displacement of a body (although not an oscillating one, with which I have less difficulty in finding *e*, but extending endlessly in a straight line).

My attempts so far to find an answer:

- One of the ways to calculate Euler’s number is with the series of the inverse factorials:

$e = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(\frac{1}{{n!}})}  = \frac{1}{{0!}} + \frac{1}{{1!}} + \frac{1}{{2!}} + \frac{1}{{3!}} + \frac{1}{{4!}} + \frac{1}{{5!}} + ... = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{{24}} + \frac{1}{{120}} + ...
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyzaiabg2
% da9maaqahabaGaaiikamaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaad6gacaGGHaaa
% aiaacMcaaSqaaiaad6gacqGH9aqpcaaIWaaabaGaeyOhIukaniabgg
% HiLdGccqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIWaGaaiyiaaaacqGH
% RaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIXaGaaiyiaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaa
% qaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaGaaiyiaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigda
% aeaacaaIZaGaaiyiaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaI0a
% GaaiyiaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaI1aGaaiyiaaaa
% cqGHRaWkcaGGUaGaaiOlaiaac6cacqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaey4kaSIaaG
% ymaiabgUcaRmaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaikdaaaGaey4kaSYaaSaa
% aeaacaaIXaaabaGaaGOnaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaaca
% aIYaGaaGinaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIXaGaaGOm
% aiaaicdaaaGaey4kaSIaaiOlaiaac6cacaGGUaaaaa!69B7!
$

- You get a similar series if you consider the displacement, after 1 second, of an object starting at position = 1 m, with v = 1 m/s and subjected to acceleration = 1 m/s^2 and to successive derivatives of position with respect to time (jerk, snap, crackle, pop... and so on ad infinitum), all of value = 1:

$\Delta r = {r_o} + {v_o}\Delta t + a\frac{{\Delta {t^2}}}{2} + j\frac{{\Delta {t^3}}}{6} + c\frac{{\Delta {t^4}}}{{24}} + p\frac{{\Delta {t^5}}}{{120}}... = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{{24}} + \frac{1}{{120}} + ...
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaeyiLdqKaam
% OCaiabg2da9iaadkhadaWgaaWcbaGaam4BaaqabaGccqGHRaWkcaWG
% 2bWaaSbaaSqaaiaad+gaaeqaaOGaeyiLdqKaamiDaiabgUcaRiaadg
% gadaWcaaqaaiabgs5aejaadshadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaakeaa
% caaIYaaaaiabgUcaRiaadQgadaWcaaqaaiabgs5aejaadshadaahaa
% WcbeqaaiaaiodaaaaakeaacaaI2aaaaiabgUcaRiaadogadaWcaaqa
% aiabgs5aejaadshadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaisdaaaaakeaacaaIYaGaaG
% inaaaacqGHRaWkcaWGWbWaaSaaaeaacqGHuoarcaWG0bWaaWbaaSqa
% beaacaaI1aaaaaGcbaGaaGymaiaaikdacaaIWaaaaiaac6cacaGGUa
% GaaiOlaiabg2da9iaaigdacqGHRaWkcaaIXaGaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaa
% caaIXaaabaGaaGOmaaaacqGHRaWkdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaI2a
% aaaiabgUcaRmaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaikdacaaI0aaaaiabgUca
% RmaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaaigdacaaIYaGaaGimaaaacqGHRaWkca
% GGUaGaaiOlaiaac6caaaa!6F1D!
$

But this situation looks very unreal.

However, there should be a real-life example, because you can easily get displacement = *e* (if I am not mistaken) when the acceleration affects only direction, not modulus. Take for example a satellite that is 1 unit away from a gravitation source and that moves tangentially by inertia at v = 1 of whatever units. If gravity acts perpendicularly to the tangential motion and the acceleration caused by gravity is $\frac{v^2}{r}$ (that is to say, with these numbers, 1), then the displacement after 1 time unit will be circular and of modulus 1 radian = $e^i$, wouldn’t it? This situation looks to me very much like compound interest, because you start with a capital (radius) and an interest rate (velocity) and then you make the interest compound and continuous, although only in terms of direction (centripetal acceleration).

But what if the satellite were heading towards the earth and what changed were the modulus of its velocity, do we lose then the possibility to involve number *e*?

Comment: Your going to *love* the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) and Fourier analysis & synthesis. ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring I had been studying it during latest months, I do love it and, well, that is what inspired the example about the satellite! I am afraid that I was inaccurate in talking about kinematics. Of course kinematics also describes waves and oscillators, but I have no problem in seeing it there; what I meant is that I am looking for it in non-oscillating phenomena.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, $e$ is ubiquitous in kinematics. For example, consider a repulsive force proportional to $x$,
$$F = kx.$$
Then the acceleration is
$$a = \frac{k}{m} x = \omega^2 x, \quad \omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}.$$
This differential equation has solutions of the form $e^{\omega t}$ and $e^{- \omega t}$. In particular, suppose that $x(0) = 1$ and $v(0) = \omega$. In that case the solution is exactly 
$$x(t) = e^{\omega t}.$$
In general, for any linear force law, the solutions will be exponentials or complex exponentials, so it's honestly hard to avoid using $e$.

Comment: I wrongly asked about a role in kinematics in general, while I should have probably referred to kinematics in a straight line. I have less problem for identifying e in oscillatory phenomena, such as waves or harmonic oscillators. But your answer is very helpful anyhow.

Comment: @Sierra This is motion in a straight line -- everything is along the $x$-axis.

Comment: You are right of course. I am being very inaccurate… Actually what I meant is: in a non-oscillatory context, that is to say, a body moving without go-and-return trip, for example one moving in a straight line without change of direction. I have edited the question in this sense.

Comment: @Sierra This is not oscillatory motion, the function $e^{\omega t}$ doesn't oscillate.

Comment: Again you are right, I was seeing what was not there: you did not talk about an oscillating spring, you did not put an i in the exponent…, but I was imagining both things… But what about an example involving gravity acting parallel to the body's velocity? Maybe e does not appear in such case because here the force is inversely proportional to distance *squared* (not linear)?

Comment: @Sierra In general $e$ appears when solving linear differential equations, e.g. when the force has a term linear in $x$ or $v$. For nonlinear differential equations, anything goes!

Comment: I wonder why, if the function does not oscillate, you use omega in the exponent, which usually denotes a frequency. I also wonder if an example could also be a car where you are progressively stepping on the gas (in proportion to displacement?)

Comment: If $x(t)=e^{\omega t}$, then $x(1)=e^\omega$. Did you mean to say $\omega=1$ as well? Or did you mean to say $x(1/\omega)=e$?

Comment: @AaronStevens You're completely right, not sure where I was going with that statement.

Comment: That is not kinematics. Kinematics has no consideration for forces. It just the relationships between position velocity and acceleration.

Answer (score 8):

A simple example is just an object starting at rest falling with a drag force proportional to the velocity of the object, $F_D=-bv$. Then the acceleration is given by

$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}=g-\frac bmv$$

Therefore, the velocity over time is given by
$$v(t)=\frac{mg}{b}(1-e^{-bt/m})$$

Typically you get $e$ popping up when the rate of change of something is proportional to itself.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I accepted the other answer because there *e* appears alone in the solution and signifying displacement. But can you please clarify this? In the last comment I asked knzhou if he could build a similar example with a car speeding up. I could ask from you a similar clarification: what if the drag force were proportional to displacement, what if a car is progressively stepping on the brake in proportion to x? If x starts at 1 and v starts at 1, after t=1, would x be *e*?

Comment: @Sierra I mean getting the actual position or velocity to be $e$ is pretty contrived. In my example you can find a time where $x$ or $v$ is equal $e$ (with appropriate units). Even objects moving at a constant velocity will have a time where the distance traveled is equal to $e$. For example, for a particle moving with a constant velocity $v=e$, then after one second $x=e$. For a particle moving at constant velocity $v=e/2$, then after two seconds $x=e$. There are many possibilities where you can find some point in time where a value is $e$.

Comment: @Sierra What is more interesting, and what I thought you were going for, is looking at instances where $e$ is involved in the underlying dynamics of the problem. When there is something changing whose rate of change is proportional to itself. In other words, as just a number there really is nothing special about $e$. It is just a real number like all other real numbers. It becomes important when you start considering "special" functions like $e^x$ whose rate of change is equal to itself.

Comment: I am aware that *e* is just 2.718 + infinite decimals... and you can find a similar number anyhwhere (eg in simple interest), although probably not with exactly with same digits if the underlying situation does not match with what you call its dynamics. I am also aware that its dynamics are a function whose rate of change is itself. In fact, the Newton series that is included in the OP has the characteristic that for each term the derivative is the previous one. This series assumes 1 in x, v and t and gives *e* but you can tweak *e*'s exponent and adapt to any other situation...

Comment: My question is that this series, with value *e* or *e* tweaked however you may imagine, reflects a situation with infinite derivatives that looked unreal. I then wondered if the case mentioned by knzhou does fit in spite of all, why is it and if another example would be one of those I mention (someone stepping on gas or brakes in proportion to displacement…). Do you get in those case jerk, snap, crackle, pop and so on ad infinitum and of dwindling values?

Comment: @Sierra Yes you would get those values ad infinitium. This isn't an issue because infinite sums can still converge.

Comment: Yes, if the infinite terms of the sequence converge to 0 (like here, since factorials always grow faster than powers), the sequence can converge to a finite value (e^t in this case). The question was as Zeno-like one:  whether the infinite terms is a list of things to be done, which would be impossible, or a way of describing what has been done.  If you tell me that dwindling acceleration/jerk/snap/crackle… formula describes a person’s displacement when he is stepping more and more on the gas pedal in proportion to r, that is fine, that would answer the question.

Comment: But how do you adjust to different conditions? If we must introduce here another exponent ω, like knzhou did, that looks fine to me, that'd be the way to tweak e to reflect particular conditions (it plays the role of interest rate, right?), but ω usually denotes angular frequency and here we have a velocity in a straight line…

Comment: @Sierra In knzhou's example if $F=-kx$ then $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ would represent an angular frequency and the motion would still be along a straight line. We can call $\omega$ an angular frequency because in that case there would be oscillations. When $F=kx$ the force is no longer restorative, but it's still useful to used the defined variable $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$. In other words, $\omega$ helps determine a quality of the motion, and then depending on that motion we can call it an angular frequency.

Comment: Once again I said "straight line" when I meant "non-oscillatory". Anyhow, I think that you answered: if the F were not restorative, if the motion were not oscillatory, you would not use \omega, you would use v, right?

Comment: @Sierra It seems like your are confusing angular frequency with angular velocity (which makes sense since they are both typically denoted by $\omega$). Motion under the force $F=-kx$ exhibits ocsillations on a straight line with an angular frequency $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$. When $F=kx$ then $\omega$ still characterizes the motion, but it's not viewed as a frequency. Neither example involves an angular velocity $d\theta/dt$, which it seems like you think $\omega$ represents here.

Comment: So... focusing on $F=kx$ (non-oscillatory motion), where there is no cycle, may the reason to still use $\omega$ be that it is regarded as a sort of average velocity within the relevant time lapse, which would thus act as the period?

Comment: @Sierra in that system $\omega$ can't represent an average velocity or period because the units are not the same, plus the displacement and velocity are growing exponentially. In that system $\omega$ just characterizes the exponential growth. I guess you could say in a time $1/\omega$ the displacement and velocity increase by a factor of $e$ though.

Answer (score 1):

Euler number ${\rm e}$ shows up in plenty of situations in dynamics, but not so many in kinematics. Any example given that involves some kind of force definition, or integration of acceleration is an example in dynamics. But you are asking about kinematics. Kinematics is the study of allowable motions.

I personally cannot think of any involving ${\rm e}$, except maybe particles moving along paths that already have ${\rm e}$ in their definitions. For example a catenary shape. And those seem contrived to me.

The real answer would be one where ${\rm e}$ arises naturally, out the process if differentiating the path to get velocity or acceleration. But if the derivative involves ${\rm e}$ then must also the things are being differentiated, and then we are back to the previous examples.